# Finding Xpath id instead of HTML tags as Xpath & using it for clicking on all the buttons on the page

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, firebug

I am trying to find the Xpath id on my webpage made on wordpress, but I am unable to get the id of it using firebug. For now I am using the following code on Java to click on a specific button:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[(@href= '/ecommerce/?add-to-cart=85')]"));
ele.click();
```

But I can only use this for a single button,if I try using it on multiple buttons it does not work as well as the problem with this code is after loading of the webpage I have to scroll down to the button for the click event to take place.
Please help me in this as I am new to this...
Thanks...

Comment: did I get you right, that you just want to click all buttons and links on the page?

Comment: yes for now i can only click on the button which is specifies above as add-to-cart=85
Also i have to scroll down to the button where it is located to get it clicked,if not the code just scrolls down but does not click...

Comment: that's selenium right? actually it should click.

Comment: yes it is selenium...

Comment: i just tried your code and it doesn't even open the page, because the path in `driver.get(...)` isn't complete. but as i typed the full path the page opened, automatically scrolled to the element and clicked it. try the latest version of selenium webdriver.

Comment: Hey,if u try to click the link here it considers the double inverted commas (") after the link so gives an error.Can u help me with the latest version of selenium and how to download it...i am using selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0...for me using this version does not scroll down to the button it just scrolls down and comes back to the top...after the button gets clicked u can find the button of add to cart confirming the button is clicked...thanx for the help...

Comment: of course it goes to the top after clicking, because the button links to the same page

Comment: no it just scrolls down to the button and comes back to the top but does not click coz if it would have clicked the button my counter on the cart would have been 1 (shown on the upper right corner).For clicking that button on the page i have to scroll down to the button where it is located,then only it clicks and the counter increases by 1 in the cart

Comment: just wanted to add i get the xpath of the button as html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/main/ul/li[4]/div/a
and when i use selenium for the button i get the following
<br> xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Add to cart')])[5] as xpath:link
<br> //a[contains(@href, '/?add-to-cart=85')] as xpath:href
<br> //li[5]/div/a as xpath:position
<br> Pls Help....

Comment: just wanted to add i get the xpath of the button as html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/main/ul/li[4]/div/a
and when i use selenium for the button i get the following
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Add to cart')])[5] as xpath:link         
//a[contains(@href, '/?add-to-cart=85')] as xpath:href            &     
//li[5]/div/a as xpath:position  
Pls Help....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select all elements whose id contains a particular substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731090/how-to-select-all-elements-whose-id-contains-a-particular-substring)

Comment: Have you tried using XPath like: `//a[contains(@href, '/ecommerce/?add-to-cart=')]` ?  This will return multiple elements however you'll have to use the `findElements` method as the result will return a list of elements.